# Scala Lists and Option

Tags: scala

I must be doing something wrong. I come form a Java background so this stuff should be easy.

I'm wanting to create a mapping between a key and multiple values held in a list:

```
var keys = Map[String, ListBuffer[String]]()
```

However, I can't seem to add a value to the list!!! What am I doing wrong??

```
def put(key: String, value: String) = {
  var valueOption = keys.get(key)
  var values = valueOption.getOrElse(ListBuffer)
  values += value
  // value not added
}
```

I do not want to use a MultiMap because I need to do some other operations which are not easy to do with a MultiMap.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a mutable or immutable Map?

Comment: import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers are right about how you're not putting the new `ListBuffer` back in the `Map`, but their example code is verbose.  A mutable `Map` has `getOrElse` and `getOrElseUpdate` methods for this. Also, use `val` not `var` for locals and the `keys` member, unless you have reason not to.  I sometimes prefer `append` to `+=`.

```
def put(key: String, value: String) = {
    keys.getOrElseUpdate(key, ListBuffer()) += value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
var valueOption = keys.get(key)
var values = valueOption.getOrElse(ListBuffer)
```

For any nonexistent key, `keys.get` will return a `None` `Option`. You then call `getOrElse`, and since the "else" part is used (because it's a `None`), a new `ListBuffer` is initialized. However, this is **all that happens**.

In particular, the new `ListBuffer` **is NOT automatically put into the map**. Such an operation wouldn't make sense - `getOrElse` is part of the `Option` API, it cannot "know" about any collection the `Option` is generated from.

To correct your problem, **you have to put the new `ListBuffer` into the map yourself**. An example if you're using a **mutable** Map:

```
def put(key: String, value: String) = {
      var valueOption = keys.get(key)
      var values = valueOption.getOrElse {val b = ListBuffer.empty[String]; keys.put(key,b); b;}
      values += value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that by calling `getOrElse(ListBuffer)` you do not insert the new ListBuffer into the Map. So you need to add an additional step:

```
def put(key: String, value: String) = {
  var valueOption = 
  var values = keys.get(key) match {
    case None => // key not yet defined
      buffer = ListBuffer()
      // insert into map!
      keys += key -> buffer
      buffer
    case Some(buffer) => buffer // key is already defined just return it
  }
  values += value
}
```

*Note that for `keys += key -> buffer` to work, i assume, that you use an mutable Map (import from scala.collection.mutable.Map) instad of the default immutable Map*

Comment: Looks like the best answer, but couldn't get it to compile (the second line `var valueOption =` just doesn't work. Then I can't understand what's going on. I don't understand the line `case Some(buffer) => buffer` - this method doesn't return anything. And `buffer` seems to be undeclared. Mystery.

Answer (score 0):

`getOrElse` will return the default ListBuffer, which is an empty ListBuffer, if key doesn't exist. You will need to associate this with you key.